# Creating a small struct in C - have some errors

Tags: c, struct

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define getch() _getch()

struct Clicker {
    int toggle;
    int average;
};

int main()
{
    struct Clicker *clicker;
    printf("Enter your toggle key: ");
    (*clicker).toggle = _getch();
    printf("Enter your average cps: ");
    scanf_s("%d", (*clicker).average);
    printf("\nCurrent settings: \nToggle: %i \nAverage:%i\n", clicker->toggle, clicker->average);
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

There is the code.
Errors:

```
'_getch' undefined, assuming extern returning int  
'scanf_s' format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *' but variadic arguemnt 1 has type int.  
uninitialized local variable 'clicker' used.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_getch` is in `conio.h` which you didn't include

Comment: What's unclear about the compiler messages?

Comment: You have at least one mistake on almost every line of this program. Do you have an instructor, with whom you can go over it in person, line by line? Because that is going to be much faster and more effective than trying to explain it all to you here.

Comment: `clicker` - You have not initialised it!

Comment: @zwol I'm reading Head First C and I have to like try I guess. Nobody to help me out.

Comment: @EdHeal I thought you didn't have to since I don't have the variables?

Comment: `(*clicker).toggle = _getch();` - You are using its value here - a value that you have not initialised

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this book, but based on what I see I suspect it is not a good book.

Comment: @zwol It was recommended to me. I'm learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you are trying to learn C by yourself, so I will actually explain all the mistakes in this program.

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

`stdio.h` should always be included using the `<>` form of `#include`. (The `""` form is for headers that are part of *your program*, and the `<>` form is for headers that come from system-provided libraries.  In complex programs the distinction can get fuzzy, but don't worry about that right now.)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define getch() _getch()
```

These three lines all do things that are Windows-specific and should be completely unnecessary in a program like this.  Remove them.

```
struct Clicker {
    int toggle;
    int average;
};
```

There is nothing wrong with this structure definition.

```
int main()
```

For historical reasons, you need to write `int main(void)`.  This is mostly harmless, but writing empty function parameter lists in C is a bad habit to get into.

```
{
    struct Clicker *clicker;
```

Here's your most important mistake: you have declared a *pointer* to a `struct Clicker`, when what it appears you *wanted* was to declare a local variable using the structure.  Write `struct Clicker clicker` instead.

Pointers are one of the most difficult aspects of the language, especially for people new to programming.  If your book doesn't devote at least a full chapter to pointers and nothing else, it's a bad textbook and you need to get a better one.

```
    printf("Enter your toggle key: ");
    (*clicker).toggle = _getch();
```

Consistent with the above change, write `clicker.toggle = ...` instead of `(*clicker).toggle =` since you no longer have a pointer.

Do not use the nonstandard function `_getch()`, use `getchar()` instead.  (There are programs that actually need to use `_getch` but this isn't one of them.)

```
    printf("Enter your average cps: ");
    scanf_s("%d", (*clicker).average);
```

Here's a place where you *have* to deal with pointers.  All of the arguments to `scanf`, after the format string, must be pointers to variables, because that is what makes it possible for `scanf` to write to the variables.  `clicker` is no longer a pointer, but what you wrote would be wrong even if we hadn't made that change, because `(*clicker).average` isn't a pointer even when `clicker` is.  What you need to write is

```
    scanf("%d", &clicker.average);
```

The `&` operator is said to *take the address* of the variable `clicker.average`, producing the pointer that `scanf` needs.

Similarly to what I said above about `_getch`, never, ever use the nonstandard function `scanf_s`.  (All of the functions whose names end in `_s` come from a well-intentioned but disastrously ineffective attempt by Microsoft to paper over a bunch of design errors in the standard C library.  They don't exist on most operating systems, and they don't fix the problems they were intended to fix.  Don't use any of them.)

When you get more experience you will come to realize that `scanf` is more trouble than it's worth, but for a trivial program like this it's OK.

```
    printf("\nCurrent settings: \nToggle: %i \nAverage:%i\n",
           clicker->toggle, clicker->average);
```

Unlike `scanf`, `printf` takes values, not pointers to variables, so this is right except that we have to change `clicker->toggle` to `clicker.toggle` and `clicker->average` to `clicker.average` because `clicker` is no longer a pointer.

In text to be printed, do not put spaces immediately before `\n`.

Even nowadays, code should be no more than 80 columns wide, because that way you can get two files of code side by side on your screen at once and still use a reasonable font size.  This is an absolutely vital thing to be able to do when you are working with a complex program.  (Also, really wide text is harder to read in general.)

```
    getchar();
```

It is bad style to put a call to `getchar` immediately before the end of the program.  When the program is done running it should just exit.  If your IDE refuses to keep the "console" window around after the program exits, get yourself a better IDE.

```
    return 1;
```

The program has not failed, so it should return 0, not 1.

Comment: Hi, I am very grateful for your help. I totally understand everything you have said - and it does actually match up with what I've been reading, which I'm glad about! I was reading about how when you pass a struct through parameters you merely create a copy, so you have to have a pointer instead in order to make changes to the original struct. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, but I urge you to find _someone_ you can talk to in person about the difference between `struct Clicker clicker;` and `struct Clicker *clicker;` until you have it completely clear in your head.

Comment: I'll look around for anyone in my area. thank you

Answer (score 0):

use getchar() instead of _getch(). also, you don't need to include "stdafx.h". remove it.avoid including headers you don't need.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have created this code by copying different solutions and snippets without a real understanding of its usage.

There might be reasons to use `_getch()` but if you don't now why you should probably use more standard solutions like `getchar()`.

Please consider the following solution using standard methods:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // use <...> instead of "..."
#include <stdlib.h>    // for malloc()
// #include "stdafx.h"     // not necessary    
// #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // not necessary
// #define getch() _getch()    // not necessary

struct Clicker {
    int toggle;
    int average;
};

int main(){
    struct Clicker *clicker = malloc(sizeof(struct Clicker));
    printf("Enter your toggle key: ");
    // (*clicker).toggle = _getch();   // use scanf()
    scanf("%d",&clicker->toggle);
    printf("Enter your average cps: ");
    scanf("%d", &clicker->average);
    printf("\nCurrent settings: \nToggle: %i \nAverage:%i\n",clicker->toggle, clicker->average);
    // getchar();  // not nessecary
    // return 1;   // 1 is usually an error exit code, use 0 instead
    return 0;
}
```

Another thing you don't seem to understand yet is the proper usage of `scanf()`. It receives a pointer (to an `int` in this case). Since you declared `clicker` as a pointer to your `struct Clicker` you need do dereference if to get access to its members `toggle` and `average`. You do this using `clicker->toggle`. Then you need a pointer to this dereferenceation which you get using `&`.

Comment: Uh, you didn't fix the most important bug - you're still reading and writing through an uninitialized pointer!

Comment: Ups, you are totally right. Hope I've fixed it now.

Comment: Yes, except that if you're going to call malloc you need to add `#include <stdlib.h>`.